# Regex get Value after a keyword

Tags: regex, vba

I try to get a value at the end of the line in which one of these keywords exists: `A0000` or `B0000`.

```
94039030900 Teile aus Holz, für Möbel, anderweit weder      415,17 EUR    ZOLLWERT      A0000        2,70000     0,00          11,21
              genannt noch inbegriffen. Hier: Schublade      426,38 EUR    EUST-WERT     B0000       19,00000     0,00          81,01
```

I try to get for `A0000` the value `11,21`

And for `B0000` the value `81,01`

This was my best try, but I did not get the Value I need: `(A0000)(.*\s)(\d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\bA0000.*\s(\d[\d,]*)
\bB0000.*\s(\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L30NXM/1). Grab Group 1 value in VBA code via `match.SubMatches(0)`.

Or, if you need both results with 1 regex:

```
\b[AB]0000.*\s(\d[\d,]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L30NXM/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `A0000` - a specific substring
- `.*\s` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then a whitespace
- `(\d[\d,]*)` - Capturing group 1: a digit followed with 0 or more digits or commas.

Comment: One question: why not use `\b(A|B)0000.*\s(\d[\d`?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I understood OP needs two different regexps to get two different outputs per input (when `A0000` used, one result, etc.).